# Is it possible to apply Schengen visa type C(90 days) with one way flight and apply Temporary residence permit at the arrival destination?

Tags: visa, schengen, study, finland, estonia

I'm going to study Master degree in Estonia start from 27 August 2018 which I have got all the document to apply for Visa (letter of university acceptance and dormitory contract of 1 year) but Thailand has no Estonian Embassy and Finland Embassy is the representative.

As I asked from the Estonian Embassy said that Finland Embassy can only issue Visa type-C with 90 days of staying which I understand that it's possible to get Visa Type-C to enter Estonia first and then apply for Temporary Residence Permit later within two months. But I'm not sure if it's possible to apply Visa type C with one way ticket flight by declaring my intention to apply Temporary Residence Permit when arrival in Estonia?

I booked only one way ticket because I have to study for two years.. but I'm afraid they will not issue Visa type C because I don't have return flight. To buy a return flight in the period of 90 days means that I will just need it to apply visa and won't use it, but if it's necessary I will have to buy it anyway. It's better than fly to the nearest Estonian Embassy and apply TRP there.(It's costly for me)

Please advice what should I do in this case? Try apply with one way flight with letter of acceptance from university or should I buy return ticket?

Emails from Tokyo's Estonian Embassy

> Thank you for your email and choosing Estonia as your studying
>   destination.
>
> The Finnish Embassy in Bangkok could only issue short-term C-visa.
>
> For studying in Estonia, you need following:
>
> ·         D- visa to enter Estonia - http://vm.ee/en/long-stay-d-visa
>
> ·         and TRP for Studying - 
>   https://www2.politsei.ee/en/teenused/residence-permit/tahtajaline-elamisluba/oppimiseks/index.dot
>
> It is advisable to make  consular appointment in Tokyo around 2-3
>   months before your departure to Estonia.
>
> You would submit the TRP application  is Tokyo, but pick it up 
>   already in Estonia.
>
> Normally it would take at least 3 working days to process the visa
>   application, from submitting to picking up.
>
> In order to expedite, you could send your documents by email in
>   advance

---

> Regarding the C-visa, please consult directly  with FI Embassy
>
> Alternatively you could apply for D-visa (long –term) in Tokyo.
>
> Please ask to send a copy  from the EAA  to you as well.

I'm also considering about apply D-Visa to Enter Estonia in Tokyo but I'm not sure if I could proceed with what I have first.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Don't pretend that you're only going for 90 days or less.  If you do that, you risk being refused for deception, which could lead to a ban.

First, if you haven't already asked your school about this, try to do so.  Your school may have had other students from Thailand, in which case it may know what the proper procedure is.  Some schools have an office for international students whose responsibilities include providing this kind of information.

If your school is no help, try asking Estonia what to do.  Estonia's diplomatic relationship with Thailand is handled [by its embassy in China](http://vm.ee/en/countries/thailand?display=estonian_representations).  The embassy's [page on long-stay visas](http://vm.ee/en/long-stay-d-visa) certainly implies that you can do this:

> A long-stay visa must be applied for in person at an Estonian representations or at the Police and Border Guard Board (PPA) in Estonia. At the time of submission of the application, 10 fingerprints of the applicant will be collected.

Still, it would be nice to have something in writing that specifically confirms your plans and instructs you to apply for a short-stay visa.  You could include a copy of such an instruction in your application.

If you find some more concrete information than is presented here, please do return and post your own answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Actually there's one Thais student whom studied in Estonia 4 years ago. He has an email from Finland Embassy ask him to get verification from the Police and Border Guard Board that it's possible to enter Estonia with Visa Type-C and then apply for Temporary Residence Permit when arrival. I tried to contact Finland embassy but they said 

"Thank you for your email. Sorry to inform you but it is not possible to apply for a visa to Estonia at the Embassy of Finland in Bangkok for this purpose. Kindly contact the Estonian Embassy regarding the matter."

Comment: @KeawaleeWarutkomain Since Finland said "kindly contact the Estonian Embassy regarding the matter" you can write to the embassy in Beijing and ask them what to do.  If they say "apply for a C visa through Finland" then you can ask both parties how to reconcile the conflicting information.

Comment: The university told me that " it is possible to apply for a visa first and then residence permit here in Estonia. Just make sure that the visa would be valid long enough - so that you would have time to apply for residence permit here. It may take approx. 2 months." and when I asked if I should apply for type-C Visa she answer "this is valid for 90 days - I think it should be enough for applying for residence permit here." Could this be something to confirm I was instructs to apply for short-stay visa?

The option to go to Tokyo's Estonian Embassy is second plan...but I still consider it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I will try to contact China's Estonian embassy again.. but I also attached emails I've got from Tokyo's Estonian embassy. Guess I should rethink about the Visa application again...but need to hurry..